# jQuery reload on window resize: loop on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using a jQuery script to reload a webpage in case the window size is being changed. 
It works well on desktop, however there is an big issue with this code on smartphones: its also executed on mobile scroll events. Whenever I open the page on my iPhone 6s and start scrolling the page is being reloaded after 2000 ms.

I found a possible solution but I'm unsure how to include this in to my code as this has to be modified for Wordpress as well (to be honest: I'm always unsure how jQuery has to be modified in order to work properly on Wordpress.)

This code does the job, but reloads the page on page scroll on mobile devices:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     /// I think this is not really needed
    })

    jQuery(window).bind('resize', function(e){
        if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
        window.RT = setTimeout(function(){
            this.location.reload(false); /* false to get page from cache */
        }, 2000);
    });

</script>
```

Some code I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437015/window-resize-executes-when-scrolling-on-mobile-devices) that would check the window size and validate it before executing the reload function. I don't know how to bind those two functions together.

```
var dwidth = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function(){
    var wwidth = $(window).width();
    if(dwidth!==wwidth){
         dwidth = $(window).width();
         console.log('Width changed');
    }
});
```

Comment: for what possible reason you might have a need to reload a page on resize?

Comment: why do you want to reload the webpage when resize...?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your question. 
Thats because of a grid-layout-plugin. The grid is arranged on pageload but messed up when the window gets resized. It has to be renewed and the layout rearranged  when the window-size is changed in order to look as it should.
@Artem

Comment: @benedikt-sahlmüller Well, it would be the same if each time when your PC froze you buy a new one. Each plugin(js script I suppose) has methods to reinit or update statements. Simply check the documentation for your JS plugin and find a method.

Comment: @artem - I understand your point. However, if I wanted to change a div's class, it would be quite the same solution I guess. Would you help me with that?

Comment: I don't understand why you commented my question in the first place @artem. Sorry, but it looks like you were not intersted in helping me with this.

Comment: @benedikt-sahlmüller I told you what you should do to make it right, now it is up to you to take this advice or skip it. If you are not familiar with JS you always can contact grid-layout-plugin developers and ask them for help to fix the issue.

Comment: Hello @artem - we discussed this and I'm really thankfull for your advice. 
Having that said - there is a different question that came to my mind: Maybe you can tell me how I could use the given code to add a css-class to a div whenever the display width is changed? 
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script reloads a webpage when the window size is changed. There is a 1000 ms delay to make sure the website is only reloaded after the resize took place.
In order to prevent page-reload on mobile scroll events, I added [this piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437015/window-resize-executes-when-scrolling-on-mobile-devices). It checks for the window-size if it really got changed.

```
var dwidth = jQuery(window).width();
jQuery(window).bind('resize', function(e){

    var wwidth = jQuery(window).width();

    if(dwidth!==wwidth){
     dwidth = jQuery(window).width();

    if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
    window.RT = setTimeout(function(){
        this.location.reload(false); /* false to get page from cache */
    }, 1000);
}
});
```

Tested in Wordpress on Chrome and on iPhone 6.